# Alternative to Record<T, G>

Tags: typescript

If I have a string value:

```
type x = 'hello';
```

And I try to use it to create in an object as key:

```
type v = {[x: x]: boolean};
```

I get this issue:

> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.

Is it possible I can create this object without `Record<x, boolean>`.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues, one you're using `x` twice.  Secondly, you want `in` as the operator instead of the colon.

```js
type x = 'hello';

type v = {
    [foo in x]: boolean;
};
```